# How Far Back Should My .fseventsd Logs Go?

Tags: filesystem

I've been trying to diagnose an issue with `fseventsd` eating up a tonne of CPU time after a restart, and I've discovered that the `.fseventsd` folder on each of my volumes contains thousands of files going back more than a year (February 2022).

What I've been struggling to find out is how far back as my `fseventsd` logs are *supposed* to go? I know that `fseventsd` allows apps to track file changes since they were last opened, but this seems excessive.

I know that I can disable `fseventsd` on a volume using `touch .fseventsd/no_log` and doing this on some volumes has reduced how long `fseventsd` churns away on startup, but I'd like to get to the root of the problem if possible, otherwise I'm going to be tempted to write a script to discard older logs, but I'm not sure if that's wise.

Comment: I have no documentary evidence as to how long it ought to be, but checking through a few drives, I have nothing going back more than about 4 weeks. 650 items in boot volume, only a dozen or so in others.